# Backgrounding, Java & init script

Tags: java, bash, shell, init

I am trying to write an init script for a java program. The program has no ability to background itself, so I'm using & to do it. It writes its logfiles to stdout.
The problem I have is regarding the RETVAL in the init script. Here's the function I'm using:

```
JAR_FILE=/opt/application/server/server.jar
JAVA=/usr/bin/java
    start() {
        echo -n $"Starting ${NAME}: "
        daemon --pidfile=${PID_FILE} --user $USER \
            $JAVA $JAVA_ARGS >> /var/log/application/server.log &
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $LOCKFILE
        return $RETVAL
    }
```

When I run the init script, the app starts up or fails nicely, the problem is that the retval is being written to the logfile, rather than to stdout:

```
[root@rpmbuild rpmbuild]# /etc/init.d/application-server start
Starting application-server:
[root@host]# tail /var/log/application/server.log
JAVA APPLICATION ERRORS ARE HERE
[FAILED]
```

Is there anyway I can make it log to stdout and also ensure that any retval (whether it good or bad) gets echoed to stdout?

Answer (score 1):

There are options on how to direct the output when using the `daemon` command

```
 -l, --errlog=spec         - Send daemon's error output to syslog or file
 -b, --dbglog=spec         - Send daemon's debug output to syslog or file
 -o, --output=spec         - Send client's output to syslog or file
 -O, --stdout=spec         - Send client's stdout to syslog or file
 -E, --stderr=spec         - Send client's stderr to syslog or file
```

I would change the output using the -o option and not redirect.  You should not have to background the task either

```
daemon -o /var/log/application/server.log -name SuperJavaProgram \
--pidfile=${PID_FILE} --user $USER $JAVA $JAVA_ARGS
```

Then you could test if it's running with `daemon --running -n SuperJavaProgram`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could print to `stderr` in java, to separate standard logs and errors. Your `>>` will redirect only stdout.

BTW, it's surprising to test `$?` whereas your program as not executed yet, because background-ed.